# Global hotkey KeyDown and KeyUp Events

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to implement a global hotkey logic in my program when I press down and up a key. The hotkey needs to be global. The behaviour is simple: When the F10 key is Down, the form is visible, when released, the form hides itself.

I managed to implement the WMHotkey procedure, but I need it to be split into Key Up and Down. Is there a way to do this with global hotkeys?

Comment: If you're trying to directly capture the messages, you're gonna have a lot of complications. Why not use Delphi's actions with their hot key support?

Comment: Hi Jerry. Are these global?

Comment: Yes. For example: https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27058

Comment: There will be complications with WM_HOTKEY, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149761/delphi-xe3-wm-hotkey-how-to-tell-when-hotkey-is-released , go for one of the alternatives.

Comment: @Jerry - Global is when the application is not in the foreground I guess.

Comment: @MatheusNeves, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41213742/6234602) could also be useful

Answer (score 0):

I managed to accomplish what I was trying to do by implementing the code that RRUZ provided in this question: [How to monitor the keyboard above all other applications and then send other keys to them instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940590/how-to-monitor-the-keyboard-above-all-other-applications-and-then-send-other-key).

Comment: So what is your answer to the question *"is there a way to do this with global hotkeys"*?